# How to compare similarity between two data frames in r?

Tags: r, similarities

## Plot

I have 3 data frames, each containing 2 variables: Gap and relative velocity.
[image]

## What I want to do

I want to estimate the "similarity" between the `observed` and `calibrated` data sets, as well as the `observed` and `menneni` data sets. What can I use as a "similarity" measure? If a distance is to be used, should I find it between every point pair and then sum it?

Comment: Why do you want to compare them? What is your objective? There is no single notion of "similarity" for data sets.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, I want to compare them to quantify how 'similar' or close the calibrated values are to the observed data. If the 'similarity' between calibrated and observed is higher than similarity between menneni and observed, then I can claim that calibrated values are a little better.

Answer (score 1):

For 1D problems the most popular approach is the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_test), implemented as ks.test in R. The Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic is effectively a measure of similarity between empirical distributions. There are apparently [2D versions](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article-lookup/doi/10.1093/mnras/202.3.615); I can't comment on their effectiveness, though. Since you data doesn't show obvious diagonal structure, you could just apply the 1D test separately to each of the 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer distance way, for your purpose, you can directly compute two new distance(i.e. Euclidean distance) variable to each record(row) and then run ordinary t-test to test whether the variable of distance between menneni and observed is higher than the variable of distance between calibrated and observed. If so, you can claim that calibrated values are a little better.

Code example:

```
# fake data
observed <- data.frame(X=rnorm(100,mean=1),Y=rnorm(100,mean=0.5))
calibrated <- data.frame(X=observed$X + rnorm(100,sd=0.1),Y = observed$Y + rnorm(100,sd=0.1))
menneni  <- data.frame(X=observed$X + rnorm(100,sd=0.5),Y = observed$Y + rnorm(100,sd=0.2))
# compute two distance variable using Euclidean distance
calibrated.distance <- sqrt(apply((observed - calibrated)^2,1,sum))
menneni.distance <- sqrt(apply((observed - menneni)^2,1,sum))
# run ordinary t-test
t.test(menneni.distance, calibrated.distance, alternative = "greater")
```

output:

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  menneni.distance and calibrated.distance
t = 10.968, df = 107.05, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.2885161       Inf
sample estimates:
  mean of x mean of y 
0.4655457 0.1256040
```

So in this example, since that `menneni.distance` is higher `calibrated.distance` is very significant, I can claim that calibrated values are a little better.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion, thank you. However, as you can see, the number of data points in `observed` and other two datasets are unequal. So, when I try to find `calibrated.distance`, I get error: `‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`